# puppet Error: Could not autoload puppet/provider/package/rpm: No child processes

Tags: puppet

On linux, I am working on exercise "Build up Environment". The exercise is to install **gcc**. I created a .pp file It has very simple package installation command.

```
package{"gcc": ensure => installed, }
```

The command is run on virtual box running vm downloaded from puppet labs.

It throws

> Error: Could not autoload puppet/provider/package/rpm: No child
>   processes.

Answer (score 0):

This is common if your internet connectivity is offline.

Verify that virtualbox can connect to the internet

https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/5118/not-able-to-install-gcc/?comment=5121#comment-5121